# i got this message :] File b'USA_Housing.csv' does not exist: b'USA_Housing.csv,what can i do

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I already looked through all similar posts on this issue, but I couldn't find any solution. So far Pandas read through all my CSV files without any problem, however now there seems to be a problem. When I do

```
df = pd.read_csv('USA_Housing.csv')
```

I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'USA_Housing.csv' does not exist: b'USA_Housing.csv
```

Comment: I'm guessing the path your running the code in has changed? You should probably provide the full path of the file, that way it works regardless of the current directory.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot or maybe an ASCII art depiction of your project file tree? As @ALollz has said, this is certainly a path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in the same directory as the .py file you are running?

If all the files are in the same directory, you can use the 'os' package and do something like:

```
files = os.listdir
csv_files = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == ".csv"]
```

This will return a list of all files and directories in the current working folder and means you can then parse through them and load the iteratively.